# gstreamer 1.0 input-selector

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I want to switch between RTSP stream and test stream.
I use input-selector and this pipeline:

```
input-selector name=selector ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! matroskamux \
streamable=false min-index-interval=100000 ! \
filesink location=test.mkv videotestsrc ! \
video/x-raw, width=1024, height=768, framerate=30/1, clock-rate=90000 ! \
x264enc ! rtph264pay ! selector.sink_0 rtspsrc name=rtspsrc \
location=rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.88.231:554/h264 retry=100 \
udp-buffer-size=30000000 latency=200 caps="application/x-rtp, \
media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264" !  \
selector.sink_1
```

I wrote python code that switches the source every 5 seconds. But only the test stream is written to the file. Also I see warnings in the logs

```
0:00:00.353575129 13560      0x23f5540 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2948:gst_base_src_loop:<udpsrc3> error: Internal data flow error.
0:00:00.353602076 13560      0x23f5540 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2948:gst_base_src_loop:<udpsrc3> error: streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)
0:00:02.177975961 13560      0x23f2ed0 WARN                 x264enc :0::<x264enc0> VBV underflow (frame 298, -14405 bits)

0:00:02.338993437 13560      0x23f2ed0 WARN                 x264enc :0::<x264enc0> VBV underflow (frame 328, -4872 bits)
```

How to fix it?

When I replace selector.sink_0 with fakesink, RTSP stream is recorded normaly.  Apparently the problem is caused by switching streams.

Comment: hm, you get not-linked - which means some elements did not expect/support the format you provide it. Do both branches have same video format?
Also I noticed that you completly lack buffering in your pipe, what about adding queue elements, for instance after input-selector and before x264enc and after rtspsrc? But this will not solve the not-linked error..

Comment: also try running with debug levels at least at level 5 to check what exactly happens - grep for "not-linked" - for the first occurence of that.

Comment: As I understand it, rtspsrc has 2 pad, and I connected only one of them. Rtspsrc works fine with this error. But I can't understand why the output file breaks when I switch pad in input-selector